# How to post two or more variables with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to post more than one variable using foreach loop into my database, i was able to post one variable using this code

```
foreach ($_POST['part'] as $key=>$value) {
if($value!='')
$part = $value;
```

Now i want to post more than one am not getting it, am trying this

```
foreach ($_POST['part'] && ($_unique_id) as $key=>$value)) {
if($value!='')
$part = $value;
$unique_id = $value;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you try can't work, look how `foreach` works. To understand, image a simple array : `$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => $value2");`. If you do a `foreach($array as $key => $value) { ... }`, you loop through your array so you will get `$key = "key1"` and `$value = "value1"` the first loop, then `$key = "key2"` and `$value = "value2"` the second time you loop.

Comment: I guess $_post data comes from a form? and unique id is just a random number for that form instance? 
Does it change for a given $_post data?
Anyway You could just do this too... first combine $_post and $unique id into one array then pass it through foreach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you would prefer to have your name attributes as arrays as in :

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="part[firstname]" />
  <input type="text" name="part[last_name]" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in php

```
foreach($_POST['part'] as $key => $value){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following form:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" />
  <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</form>
```

You can read the post in PHP with the following:

```
$firstName = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
```

Hope this gives you an idea how it works, not completely sure why you would need a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_POST['part'] as $key=>$value)) {
if($value!='' && $_unique_id[$i]!='')
$part = $value;
$unique_id = $_unique_id[$i];
$i++;
}
```

Use this way its work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try this

foreach (array_combine($part, $unique_id) as $part_value => $unique_id_value)
```